# Why does jquery's addClass and removeClass functions not work in this case?

Tags: jquery

In a page I'm working on, jquery's `addClass()` and `removeClass()` only work sporadically.

Check out:
http://retype.se/temp/scrolltest/test.html

Line 162-171 for example:

```
if(direction === 'down'){
     console.log('downer');
 console.log(affected);
 $(affected).removeClass('attached');
 $(affected).removeClass('parked-top');
 $(affected).addClass('parked-bottom');
}
```

It writes downer and the actual element to log, but does not change classes.

It does not throw an error or anything, but just ignores it.

**Edit: saved it to jsfiddle,**
http://jsfiddle.net/at9dZ/2/

As you can see, if you uncomment the alert above these lines, it will alert...

Comment: where is `affected` defined ?

Comment: This would be easier to debug in a jsfiddle

Comment: confirm that `direction` equals `'down'` and that `affected` contains the expected element(s) at that point in the code.

Comment: yes, direction is down and affected contain the right elements. believe me... i can run alerts and logs on both sides of these lines and get the expected results.

Comment: you dont need to use `$(affected)` since `affected` is already a jQuery object

Comment: and instead off `var affected = $(this).children('.price');` use `var affected = $(this).siblings('.price')`

Answer (score 4):

Check how you're caching the selector:

```
var affected = $(this).parent('.product').children('.price');
```

So you work with the object `affected` directly instead of using the jQuery selector again.

```
if (direction === 'down'){
    console.log('downer');
    console.log(affected);
    affected.removeClass('attached');
    affected.removeClass('parked-top');
    affected.addClass('parked-bottom');
}
```

Also, you can pretty this up by doing the following (just sugar, really):

```
affected.removeClass('attached parked-top').addClass('parked-bottom')
```

If the code is working with breakpoints but not at other times, that means that the DOM probably isn't loaded when the code is executed and jQuery can't "find" the elements. Wrap your code in:

```
$(function() {
    // Code here
});
```

or..

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
// Code Here
});
```

to ensure that it executes correctly.

Comment: Nice catch. That's why I find it handy to prefix my variables which should contain jQuery selectors with a `$`, i.e: `$affected`. Just my personal preference.

Comment: jonas, I set a breakpoint at 160 and stepped through the code in console - the classes were added and removed as intended. You may want to try the same to see if maybe there's another logic error.

Comment: Thanks, but does it work if you run it without breakpoints? it doesn't for me.

Comment: Nic, thanks again but document.ready() does not seem to be it either, updated the fiddle.

Comment: @jonas I think your top function is overriding your second function. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish so it is a bit tough to fix, but the syntax is correct. You've got a logic issue with the `.product` and `.product .bottom` waypoint handlers as it appears they're being triggered simultaneously.